# Java backend: REST, authenticated with Google sign in, now what?

Tags: java, session, jersey, google-oauth, google-openid

I have an application which is composed by a javascript frontend, and a Java backend deployed in Tomcat.
The communication between frontend and backend is all via REST. I am using Jersey for this.

I followed the official documentation to add Google sign-in in my application: 
https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/
and successfully managed to authenticate with the backend:

```
GoogleIdToken idToken = verifier.verify(idTokenString);
if (idToken != null) {...
```

The question is: **how do I have to proceed now?** Following the documentation here
https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OpenIDConnect#authenticatingtheuser
it says

> After obtaining user information from the ID token, you should query
>   your app's user database. If the user already exists in your database,
>   you should start an application session for that user. ...

Should I just start a normal java webapp session? (with the only difference that I got the user credentials from Google instead of directly from my frontend).

- If yes, how do I start the application session?
- If not, what do I have to do?

I am completely lost here. Please help.

Comment: How do you currently manage the authentication without Google ("directly with your frontend")?

Comment: I am not managing the authentication without Google yet. That´s the step I am trying to do after getting the answer to my question. But I guess I would ask for e-mail/password and that´s all. So I guess I have to manage the session after being authenticated via Google, Facebook or my custom authentication the same way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My above question was oriented. Once authenticated with Google, you have to do the exact same thing as what you would do after having checked the email/password: create a session with the username.

Answer (score 1):

I think this just means that you should "cache" the authentication information in some way and not re-authenticate against the backend with every request.

This is just one implementation to trade a google provided token into a token known to your rest-api (where the token could be the session id in case of a clustered session backend).